# Java client framework / API to call Windows phone push notification service

Tags: java, windows-phone

Does anyone know if there is a Java client framework / API to call Windows phone push notification service?  I know there is a [JavaPNS](http://code.google.com/p/javapns/) project, which is specific to Apple PNS.
I am looking for something similar to that, but specific to Windows phone.

Any help?

Comment: Your are looking for Java SDK/API that is able to send message to your windows Phone application

Answer (score 2):

Java-mpns seems to be close to what you are looking for.

https://github.com/notnoop/java-mpns

Comment: Unfortunately it does not support authenticated connections which means you can send at most 500 pushes per day. And it seems to be abandoned. The last commit was 11 month ago.

Comment: @DirkJäckel I fixed the bug ant it works well now. See https://github.com/plucury/java-mpns

Comment: @plucury Oh thanks! I have to correct myself about the 500 pushes per day. It is per app, day and user. So unless you want to push more than 500 times to one user (which is a lot) it is not a problem. And it's not abandoned :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've developed a solution with Spring and Apache Commons HTTP Client for sending RAW messages using WNS (Windows Notification Push Service)

Insert this dependencies on your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

And the following lines on applicationContext.xml

```
<bean class="java.lang.String" id="authenticateUrlPostWNS">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>https://login.live.com/accesstoken.srf</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
<util:map id="authenticateWNSHeaders">
    <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
</util:map>
<util:map id="authenticateWNSPostParams">
    <entry key="grant_type" value="client_credentials" />
    <entry key="client_id" value="ms-app://" />
    <entry key="client_secret" value="" />
    <entry key="scope" value="notify.windows.com" />
</util:map>
<util:map id="sendMessageWNSHeaders">
    <entry key="X-WNS-Type" value="wns/raw" />
    <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/octet-stream" />
    <entry key="X-WNS-RequestForStatus" value="true" />
    <entry key="X-NotificationClass" value="3" />
</util:map>
```

*Remember to fill client_id and client_secret

In my project, I've divided the implementation in four classes, which I'm going to describe below

OAuthToken is used to store and format the access token:

```
public class OAuthToken {
    private String token;
    private String tokenType;

    public OAuthToken(String token, String tokenType) {
        super();
        this.token = token;
        this.tokenType = tokenType;
    }

    public String getAuthorization() {
        return StringUtils.capitalize(tokenType) + " " + token;
    }
}
```

The HttpClientFactory (shown bellow) is used to create a new client whenever you send a message. If you reuse the same HttpClient to send a message, WNS time-out after the second message sent. I don't know why that happens, but it solved when I stopped reusing the client.

```
@Service
public class HttpClientFactory {
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;

    public HttpClient create() {
        SystemDefaultHttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT);
        httpClient.getParams().setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, TIMEOUT);
        httpClient.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(NumberUtils.INTEGER_ZERO, false));
        return httpClient;
    }

}
```

This is a base class, as you wish, you can pull down all code to WindowsPushNotificationMediator

```
public abstract class AbstractCloudMediator {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractCloudMediator.class.getSimpleName());
    @Autowired
    private HttpClientFactory clientFactory;

    @Autowired
    protected ObjectMapper mapper;

    public abstract boolean sendMessage(Jogador destinatario, Action mensagem);

    protected String postToString(HttpPost post) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        HttpResponse response = executeMethod(post);

        return responseToString(response);
    }

    protected String responseToString(HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        InputStream conteudoResposta = response.getEntity().getContent();
        try {
            return IOUtils.toString(conteudoResposta);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(conteudoResposta);
        }
    }

    protected HttpResponse executeMethod(HttpPost post) throws IOException, ClientProtocolException {
        LOG.info("posting to... " + post);
        return clientFactory.create().execute(post);
    }
}
```

The next class should do the main work, but remember to create a `cloudMessagingDAO` to retrieve and store your access token.
You should replace the class `Jogador` for another class that contains the client URL, used to send a message to a Windows Phone device.

```
@Service(SharedConstants.WINDOWS_CLOUD_BEAN)
public class WindowsPushNotificationMediator extends AbstractCloudMediator { // NO_UCD (test only)
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WindowsPushNotificationMediator.class.getName());
    private static final String KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "access_token";
    private static final String KEY_TOKEN_TYPE = "token_type";

    @Resource(name = "authenticateWNSHeaders")
    private Map<String, String> authenticateWNSHeaders;

    @Resource(name = "authenticateWNSPostParams")
    private Map<String, String> authenticateWNSPostParams;

    @Resource(name = "sendMessageWNSHeaders")
    private Map<String, String> sendMessageWNSHeaders;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticateUrlPostWNS")
    private String authenticateUrlPostWNS;

    @Autowired
    private CloudMessagingDAO cloudMessagingDAO;

    private OAuthToken oathToken;

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(Jogador destinatario, Action mensagem) {
        try {
            OAuthToken token = getToken();
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(mensagem);
            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString, Consts.UTF_8);
            return sendMessage(destinatario, entity, token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private boolean sendMessage(Jogador destinatario, HttpEntity entity, OAuthToken token) throws IOException {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(destinatario.getCloudMessagingInfo());// this is the client url

        post.addHeader("Authorization", token.getAuthorization());
        addPostHeaders(post, sendMessageWNSHeaders);

        post.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse response = executeMethod(post);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED) {
            return sendMessage(destinatario, entity, getNewToken());
        }
        Header[] allHeaders = response.getAllHeaders();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Header header : allHeaders) {
            builder.append(header.getName() + ": " + header.getValue());
            builder.append('\n');
        }
        LOG.info(builder.toString());
        return response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK;
    }

    private void addPostHeaders(HttpPost post, Map<String, String> postHeaders) {
        for (String key : postHeaders.keySet()) {
            post.addHeader(key, postHeaders.get(key));
        }
    }

    private OAuthToken getToken() throws IOException {
        if (oathToken == null) {
            //You should store your access token, so you can reuse it until it expires
            String token = cloudMessagingDAO.getValue(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
            String tokenType = cloudMessagingDAO.getValue(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE);
            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(token) && StringUtils.isNotBlank(tokenType)) {
                return oathToken = new OAuthToken(token, tokenType);
            }
            return getNewToken();
        }
        return oathToken;
    }

    private OAuthToken getNewToken() throws IOException {
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(authenticateUrlPostWNS);
        addPostHeaders(post, authenticateWNSHeaders);
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String key : authenticateWNSPostParams.keySet()) {
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(key, authenticateWNSPostParams.get(key)));
        }
        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
        HttpResponse response = executeMethod(post);
        String conteudo = responseToString(response);

        LOG.info(conteudo);
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            throw new NegocioException("Falha ao autenticar no serviço: " + conteudo);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, String> resultMap = mapper.readValue(conteudo, HashMap.class);
        cloudMessagingDAO.setValues(resultMap);
        return oathToken = new OAuthToken(resultMap.get(KEY_ACCESS_TOKEN), resultMap.get(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE));
    }
}
```