# How to send a push notification in windows phone app using java?

Tags: java, windows-phone, push-notification

I am aware of creating push notification in java for Android and Apple apps. Now i want to create a push notification service for windows phone app. Tried little googling but didnt found enough resources.
Can anyone help me with good resources for creating push notifications in java for a windows phone app.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126907/java-client-framework-api-to-call-windows-phone-push-notification-service/25145352#25145352

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try that [JAVA MPNS](https://github.com/notnoop/java-mpns)

It's 3 years old but works and supoorts `toast/tile/raw` types. Build it from source, add into project and follow samples.

Comment: Its 3 years old.. :| Will try it.